# Cannot update fulfillment in Shopify

Tags: json, shopify, updates, fulfillment

I have this: `PUT/admin/orders/450789469/fulfillments/255858046.json` in updating the fulfillment.

I have this following json data to update:

```
{ "fulfillment": {"id":3604167143,"order_id":4015640143,"status":"success","tracking_numbers":"6J700123456","variant_inventory_management":"shopify"}}
```

It returns a 400 error - Bad request.

Is there anything I've missed in passing the data to update? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to send `tracking_numbers` as an array, rather than a string. Try something like this:

```
{
    "fulfillment": {
        "id": 3604167143,
        "order_id": 4015640143,
        "status": "success",
        "tracking_numbers": ["6J700123456"],
        "variant_inventory_management": "shopify"
    }
}
```

If you look in the body of the response from Shopify then you can sometimes find more info about what went wrong.

Comment: Why does the fulfillment_status was not changed to fulfill ? It is still pending.

Comment: Is it possible that the order still has line items that haven't been fulfilled?